# Are static initializers guaranteed to be called for AspectJ aspects?

Tags: java, classloader, aspectj

This is my first question so please be gentle. :-) I know AspectJ can create pointcuts on static initializers of java *classes*. But the question is whether a static initializer *in* an aspect, as below, is guaranteed to be called exactly once:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  private static Map configuration;
  static {
    // Some initialization stuff
    configuration = Config.getConfiguration();
  }
  ... use the "configuration" map in pointcuts and advices
}
```

In other words, is an aspect loaded like a java class is loaded? Is this done via a ClassLoader? I am guessing yes - and it seems to work - but I am looking for a guarantee along those lines.

Comment: According to a response on the aspectj-users mailing list, Ramnivas Laddad (author of the excellent book AspectJ In Action) says that static initializers in aspects ARE called just as they are for classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspectJ works using bytecode modification. This modification can happen wither at compile time ("compile-time weaving", or CTW), or at load-time ("Load-time weaving", or LTW).

If you want to be sure, then I suggest you use the aspectj compiler to perform CTW on your example, and then pass the resulting class files through the `javap` tool (or something like it) to see what it has actually generated. That should give you the reassurance that it is (or isn't) doing what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks - and I know that an aspect is currently implemented much like a class. But the documentation I've seen takes pains to say that aspects are *not* classes, so I was looking for an authoritative statement that says that it will always continue to work this way, not just that it does right now. Something like "an AspectJ aspect has the same lifecycle as a java class."